# Copying a File to multiple destination paths using powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, scripting, coding-style

so my goal is to copy a folder with files in it to multiple different destination paths Ex.(destination path 1 - \computer1\c$\Users\computer1\Desktop, destination path 2 - \computer2\c$\Users\computer2\Desktop).

This code that I've found works fine, but only with the same destination path. My destination paths are all different.

```
$ServerList = Get-Content "C:\Users\test\Desktop\test.txt"
$SourceFileLocation = "C:\Users\computer1\Desktop\testing"
$Destination = "C$\users\Test\Desktop"
foreach ($_ in $ServerList)
{Copy-Item $SourceFileLocation -Destination \\$_\$Destination -Recurse -PassThru}
```

If anyone has any ideas please help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Make `$Destination` an array and loop through it like you're doing for `$ServerList`

Comment: Also Join-Path is needed to join two paths. I think that C$ is not a valid drive path.

Comment: hi Jesse, I just tried that and I got an error saying "The network name cannot be found"

Comment: hey @Wasif Hasan, can you explain a bit more please and thank you.

Comment: @WasifHasan `\\ComputerName\C$` is a hidden administrative share exposes the root of C: on the specified computer. It comes with every installation of Windows. @Classified, make sure that the computer name you're putting in the destination path is correct and is able to be resolved by your computer.